# Embed.set_image is not showing image

Tags: python, discord.py

When pass a URL for to the method `Embed.set_image()`, no image is sent. It's a HTTP(S) and according to the docs it should open.

The link will redirect to another one this might be the issue but I can't find a way around that.

What is weird is that sometime is works and sometimes it doesn't.

Here are two samples:

https://squad.gamepedia.com/Special:FilePath/Kamdesh_Invasion_V1_CAF.jpg (Doesn't work)

https://squad.gamepedia.com/Special:FilePath/Al_Basrah_AAS_V1.jpg (Working)

Simple code to test with:

```py
@bot.command()
async def a(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Test')
    embed.set_image(url="https://squad.gamepedia.com/Special:FilePath/Kamdesh_Invasion_V1_CAF.jpg")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: The first URL redirects to another URL, so you may just want to use the final address ([copy this one](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/squad_gamepedia/images/3/30/Kamdesh_Invasion_V1_CAF.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20210225064743)).

Comment: @JacobLee Thanks for that but both of them do the same. I have a whole system to get the link doing what you just said will not work. **What is the size limit for `set_image`**? Since the one not working 4.2MB and the one working 3.7MB

Comment: I believe the size limit is the same as for sending files in Discord itself, which would be 8.00 MB, if I'm not mistaken (50.00 MB with Nitro).

Comment: Is the embed sent but the image not sent?

Comment: @12944qwerty Yes, but the image is not shown. If using the redirected link it works. What is confusing is that both of them are the same website. One redirects and the other fails

Comment: You're not catching any errors right? Can you make sure that all errors are being printed? (I'm not sure as to why this is happening so I'm thinking of all possible things)

Comment: Have you tried sending the link onto discord to see if it would convert? What about sending a bytes-like array as a File onto discord?

Comment: Yes I have tried to send the redirected link above, it shows it perfectly in the embed. So it must be with the redirect, what is confusing me is that both are the same format. I really appreciate u trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research appeared that the URL is not redirecting correctly.

This is the old (not working all the time)

```
https://squad.gamepedia.com/Special:Redirect/file/Kamdesh_Invasion_V1_CAF.jpg
```

The new URL

```
https://squad.gamepedia.com/Special:FilePath/Kamdesh_Invasion_V1_CAF.jpg
```

Changed from `Special:FilePath` to `Special:Redirect/file`